# convert website's xml to memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a web page that generates an rss feed dynamically.

```
http://localhost/syn/atom.aspx
```

This produces the rss feed dynamically.

i am trying to access the rss from my external application, and in this particular case, i need to download the rss page into a memory stream.

Is this possible?

Comment: google for  `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/syn/rss.aspx");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
return dataStream;
```